# Alternative to failing Interpreter["Location"] for Postcodes in the United Kingdom

Tags: curated-data, geographics, interpreter

[`Interpreter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html) constrained for the *form* `"Location"` returns coordinates of a geographic location.

For example

```
Interpreter["Location"]["Mount Everest"]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{27.9881, 86.9253}]
> ```

That seemly works for some UK Postcodes

```
Interpreter["Location"] /@ {"NW6 1PG", "UB6 0HY", "W6 0RF"}
```

> ```
>  { GeoPosition[{51.5472, -0.191049}],
>    GeoPosition[{51.5558, -0.334926}],  
>    GeoPosition[{51.4941, -0.234571}] }
> ```

but strangely not for others

```
Interpreter["Location"] /@ {"NW6 1EH", "NW6 1UE", "NW6 5AE"}
```

[image]

**What alternative methods are there to get a [`GeoPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoPosition.html) from a UK Postcode?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem

This problem has been acknowledged by *Wolfram Technical Support* [CASE:3913717] (July 2017)

> *"[...] at this point in time, they haven't optimized interpreter to handle these inputs [in Mathematica 11.1]. As such it isn't surprising that some may work, but we are unable to guarantee that they all will.[...] Further conversion of these postal codes to GeoPositions would require a custom interpreter. "*

### A solution

There is a Mathematica package by Arnoud Buzing that uses a web API from [api.postcodes.io](https://api.postcodes.io). The packages is available at [github.com/arnoudbuzing/postcode](https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/postcode).

A representative function of the package (with some modifications) is

```
postcodes[codes : List[_String ..]] := Module[
  {request, response},
  request = HTTPRequest[
    "http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes"
    , <|
     Method -> "POST"
     , "Body" -> {"postcodes" -> codes}
     , "Headers" -> {"content-type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", 
       "user-agent" -> "Wolfram HTTPClient 11.1"}
     |>
    ];
  response = URLRead[request];
  ImportString[response["Body"], {"RawJSON"}]["result"]]
```

The API allows list of only 100 code per query, so this needs to be modified to divide longer lists in smaller chunks. Several other related functionalities are also available.

### Example

```
Interpreter["Location"] /@ {"NW65AR", "OX49 5NU"}
```

> ```
> {GeoPosition[{51.5313, -0.195886}], GeoPosition[{51.6595, -1.07229}]}
> ```

```
Query[All, "result", GeoPosition[#["latitude"], #["longitude"]] &][
 postcodes[{"NW65AR", "OX49 5NU"}]]
```

> ```
> {GeoPosition[51.6559, -1.06977], GeoPosition[51.533, -0.197077]}
> ```

### Warning

Beware that the [`GeoPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoPosition.html) obtained by different methods are not identical. `Interpreter["Location"]` provides incorrect coordinates.